# Как считать данные из SqlDataReader в динамический массив

Tags: c#, sql-server

Здравствуйте,

Я создавая собственный класс работы с базой данных (MS SQL) на Visual C# столкнулся с проблемой.

Есть задумка чтобы одна из функций класса будет возвращать массив данных считанных из таблицы базы данных.

Примерный вид:

```
    public Array reader(string sqlquery)
    {

            SqlConnection myConnection = this.connect();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, myConnection);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            this.RecordsAffected = myReader.RecordsAffected;
            this.HasRows = myReader.HasRows;

            if (myReader.HasRows)
              {
                  создать массив 
                  while (myReader.Read())
                  {
                      в массив поместить (myReader)

                  }

              }
           myConnection.Close()

           return получившийся массив ; 
    }
```

Если где то ошибаюсь поправьте плиз.

Как реализовать преобразование myReader в строку массива?

Может ещё можно как то поместить его в списки(list)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно создать сущность, в которой вы будете хранить ваши данные, полученные из запроса, до цикла создать список этих сущностей (List<YourEntity>) и в каждом шаге цикла создавать новый объект данной сущности, заполняя его данными из БД и конвертируя каждое значение. Как то так:

```
//создать список
var list = new List<Entity>();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    //создать новую сущность
    var entity = new Entity();

    //получить значение из "ридера"
    //преобразовать к нужному типу
    //заполнить сущность
    entity.Property1 = myReader.GetInt(0); //GetDouble(1), GetFloat(2).........

    //добавить сущность в список
    list.Add(entity);
}
...
```

И такой бред для каждой новой таблицы в БД: ручное преобразование типов и тд...

Comment: Намучился сделал даже с двумерными списками реализацию. 
Потом нашёл способ лучше :)
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

А что именно ты хочешь возвращать? Все что вернет запрос?
смотри в сторону [SqlDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues.aspx). Заполняешь массив объектов данными из текущей строки, кидаешь массив в лист и возвращаешь лист. В общем как-то так.

Comment: Можешь показать на примере функции которая сверху написана.
Возвращать лист тоже удобно.

Comment: по описанию как то не то:

Возвращаемое значение

Тип: System.Int32
Количество экземпляров объекта Object в массиве.

Может не совсем то?

Comment: по ссылке есть пример использования этого метода. Что-то типа

List<object[]> result = new List<object[]>();while(reader.Read())
{
  object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
  int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);
  result.Add(values);
}
return result;

Answer (score 0):

Просто я только разбираюсь с visual c#, раньше писал на c++ builder, а потом полностью переключился на web, сейчас потребовалось написать проект, вот и начал разбираться с программой. Написал основные классы, и продумываю как лучше работать с mssql, как проработать класс для него.

И не разбирался с Linq2Sql, если он более толков, поделись ссылочкой на примеры классов для работы с ним.

Comment: Просто я только разбираюсь с visual c#, раньше писал на c++ builder, а потом полностью переключился на web, сейчас потребовалось написать проект, вот и начал разбираться с программой. Написал основные классы, и продумываю как лучше работать с mssql, как проработать класс для него. 

И не разбирался с Linq2Sql, если он более толков, поделись ссылочкой на примеры классов для работы с ним.